# How to remove draggability from an element with Ext JS?

Tags: extjs

I have a `div` that I want to make draggable or not, depending on the state of some other stuff on my page.  I seem to be able to easily make it draggable, but I can't seem to figure out how to best remove the draggability from the `div`.

I am making it draggable with:

```
var dd = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DDProxy', mydiv, 'myDDGroup', { isTarget: false });
```

And I've tried to then remove the draggability by removing the only group it's a member of

```
dd.removeFromGroup('myDDGroup');
```

and just destroying the `dd` object with

```
delete dd;
```

Neither of these seem to actually keep me from starting a drag on the element. I suspect I should be able to use the `b4Drag` override in some way to simply cancel a drag of my `div` before it even begins, rather than toggling the draggable state of the `div` at all, but I can't seem to find docs on how I might cancel the drag during the `b4Drag` call.

So, how can I make a `div` undraggable after I have already made it draggable?

Comment: Have you made it work?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me.

Here is the [JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/01gx33h0/](http://jsfiddle.net/01gx33h0)

```
var dd = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DDProxy', 'test123', 'myDDGroup', { isTarget: false });
Ext.fly('btn123').on('click', function() {
  dd.removeFromGroup('myDDGroup');
});
```

Can you give me the sample code where it is not working. And what version of ExtJs are using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to unreg. Not removeFromGroup.
It just removes from group. But events are not removed on that element.

```
dd.unreg();
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1eun

Answer (score 0):

When looking at something specific that needs to be dragged, you might consider that allowing dragging is something users expect, for general ease of use you might try the `ondragstart="return`, this could be appended to your images, or links like so:

`<a ondragstart="return false" href="#link">link</a>`.